Configure trust list in kickstart's %post section
I am trying to execute comands that performs certain security configurations on my recently installed system (RHEL 9).
%post --nochroot
wget -P /mnt/sysimage/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Certification_authority.crt
update-ca-trust
%end

The certificate is being copied successfully. The second command is not executed on the installed system.
How do I add my root certificate to the system being installed?
